# Grade de Hexágonos - retornar vizinhos

Tags: javascript, algoritmo

Estou escrevendo um simulador de um jogo chamado Iso-Path. Consiste em uma grade hexagonal, sendo ela mesma formada de hexágonos

[Você pode ver o que já fiz neste link](http://webfront.com.br/isopath/)

Mas empaquei na hora de pegar os vizinhos de certa célula.

Por exemplo, a célula 5 tem 6 vizinhos (0, 1, 4, 6, 10, 11)

[image: A grade]

Então vamos ao código

```
var tabuleiro = "4567654";

podeMover(5, 0); // => true
podeMover(5, 1); // => true
podeMover(5, 4); // => true
podeMover(5, 7); // => false (Não são vizinhos)
```

Uma célula na borda horizontal teria como vizinho também a célula do outro extremo horizontal. Logo...

```
podeMover(22, 27); // true
```

[image: Vizinhos + teletransporte]

Eu poderia muito bem criar uma array com cada vizinho manualmente, mas eu gostaria de saber como fazer isso proceduralmente.

O tabuleiro seria sempre um hexágono composto por hexágonos menores, logo tabuleiros válidos seriam representados por strings como (em que cada número descreve a quantidade de hexágonos menores em uma linha do hexágono maior, indicados da esquerda para direita como aparecem de cima pra baixo na figura):

```
"3456543"
"4567654" // Padrão Iso-path
"567898765" // ... etc
```

Comment: Eu sei que não é a resposta que procuras, mas quando andei a ler um pouco sobre esse tópico, achei este site bem útil, muita informação sobre desenvolvimento para jogos, envio o link para a parte dos vizinhos, pode ter algo que te ajude a encontrar a solução https://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#neighbors (em ingles)

Comment: Se puder dizer como é a estutura que armazena os hexágono, posso até tentar ajudar. Por exemplo, se é linha x posição, se é alinhado à esquerda ou ao centro. etc (lembrando ainda que em grande parte das vezes, um mapa de hexágonos é a mesma coisa que um quadriculado, com a única diferença que a cada linha ou coluna se desloca um eixo em 50% da unidade)

Comment: @Bacco Mas neste caso cada linha tem um tamanho. E como o objetivo é pegar os vizinhos, acredito que seja importante o fato de hexágonos terem mais arestas (portanto, mais vizinhos).

Comment: @bfavaretto exemplo de quadriculado com 6 vizinhos, coordenadas X e Y apenas: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWfvy.png (o "segredo" é o offset). Por isso pedi a estrutura, pois dependendo da maneira que ele armazena tem maneiras diferentes de fazer. Dependendo do caso o tamanho da linha pode fazer diferença, dependendo não. Agora, claro que eu também acho importante uma resposta que considere apenas o número do quadrado, para que seja canonica (ainda assim, neste caso ideal, em algum lugar temos que armazenar o tamanho do hexágono, seja pelo lado ou quantidade de casas).

Comment: Essas regras atrapalham um pouco, pq não sabemos se é só horizontal, vertical, e foge do que seria natural (ir pro lado oposto, e não "espelhar"): "Uma célula na borda horizontal teria como vizinho também a célula do outro extremo horizontal. Logo..."

Answer (score 1):

Acho que há duas soluções possíveis;

1) achar uma fórmula matemática que, baseada no tamanho do super-hexágono, retorne os números dos hexágonos vizinhos. Seria muito rápido, porém pouco flexível.

2) Usar uma estrutura semelhante a uma lista duplamente encadeada, porém com 6 links em vez de dois:

```
class Hexagono {
     int numero;
     Hexagono *uma_hora;
     Hexagono *tres_horas;
     Hexagono *cinco_horas;
     Hexagono *sete_horas;
     Hexagono *nove_horas;
     Hexagono *onze_horas;
}
```

(Usei C++ para ilustrar o fato de que Hexagono é um objeto e que os links do hexágono para os vizinhos devem ser referências, não valores, mas a ideia é prontamente aplicável a qualquer outra linguagem.)

Daria um certo trabalho para criar os hexágonos, porque seria preciso atribuir seus "vizinhos", mas uma vez criados, fica fácil saber quantos e quais vizinhos cada um tem.

Answer (score 0):

Então xará, não sei se você reparou, mas a identificação do vizinho é bastante simples, no caso da célula escolhida, o valor do vizinho sempre vai ser o
 valor_da_célula - 5, valor_da_célula - 4, valor_da_célula - 1, valor_da_célula + 1,
valor_da_célula + 5 e valor_da_célula + 6.
Não sei como suas células são inseridos, mas caso você esteja utilizando filas duplamente encadeadas, ficaria fácil você pegar as células que não tem vizinho, fazendo uma comparação como `se existe(valor_da_célula - 1) resulta em falso` estão ele vai substituir a posição da célula que estaria nessa posição, pela próxima célula que não possui célula na posição `valor_da_célula + 1`.
Espero, sinceramente, ter te ajudado de alguma forma. Se não, explique como está sendo inserido as células pra gente te ajudar melhor. Valeu.